# How to divide 1 by 25(1/25) and get result .04 in java

Tags: java, math

It returns `0` if performed with plain BODMAS operation.

I have something like this:

```
int mbUsed=1;

int mbTotal=25;

int percent=(mbUsed/mbTotal)*100;
```

Answer (score 1):

`1/25` will return 0, since int division can't return fractions.

You can cast to double for floating point division :

```
int percent=(int) ((double)mbUsed/mbTotal)*100;
```

Or if you want a more accurate result :

```
double percent = ((double)mbUsed/mbTotal)*100;
```

If you want to stay with int division, you can change the order of the operators :

```
int percent = (100*mbUsed)/mbTotal;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `int` data type in `Java` contains whole values. You should instead store your values in the `double` or `float` data types, as they can contain decimal points.

Here you can see an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int iVal1 = 1;
    int iVal2 = 25;
    int iVal3 = iVal1 / iVal2;

    System.out.println("Integer storage, int variables: " + iVal3);

    double dVal1 = iVal1 / iVal2;

    System.out.println("Double storage, int variables: " + dVal1);

    double dVal2 = (double) iVal1 / (double) iVal2;

    System.out.println("Double storage, double variables: " + dVal2);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Integer storage, int variables: 0
Double storage, int variables: 0.0
Double storage, double variables: 0.04
```

Notice how the values you are dividing also have to have at least `double` precision. In my example I simply type cast them to a `double` (seeing as they are whole numbers, it will make no difference), but you could also store them in `double` data types as well.

Comment: Upvote for providing great output that shows the differences!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use BigDecimal, so for other ratio's You can manipulate scale:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html
This is especially recommended for currencies.

```
BigDecimal dividend= BigDecimal.ONE;
BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal(25);
BigDecimal result = dividend.divide(divisor );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider just using doubles for your values `mbUsed` and `mbTotal`.

Example:

```
double mbUsed = 1;
double mbTotal = 25;
double percent = (mbUsed * 100)/mbTotal;
```

You could even add a decimal format, in case the numbers for `mbUsed` and `mbTotal` change.

Example:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Then, you can use `df.format(percent)` in a `System.out.println` statement to display the percentage rounded to two decimal points.

Here is an example of some code that compiles as it should:

```
double mbUsed = 1;
double mbTotal = 25;
double percent = (mbUsed * 100)/mbTotal;   

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

System.out.println("The number used: " + df.format(mbUsed));
System.out.println("The total number: " + df.format(mbTotal));
System.out.println("The percentage used is: " + df.format(percent) + "%.");
```

This outputs:

```
The number used: 1.00
The total number: 25.00
The percentage used is: 4.00%
```

I hope this works well for you!